# Remove object from Arraylist Java, only working in specific scenarios

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

I'm trying to remove an object from an arraylist in java using android studio.

```
public class ToDoListManager {

    private List<ToDoItem> items;

    public ToDoListManager() {
        items = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

        items.add(new ToDoItem("Get Milk", false));
        items.add(new ToDoItem("Walk the dog", true));
        items.add(new ToDoItem("Go to the gym", false));
    }

    public List<ToDoItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(ToDoItem item) {
       items.remove(item);
    }
}
```

I've been calling the removeItem function from a keypress

When I add, let's say "test" to the array, it successfully adds it using  items.add(item), however when I try items.remove(item) given the same string, it won't work.
It works if I do `items.remove(1)`, but not if I do `items.remove("test")`

How could I fix this? I've tried many different ways. Thanks.

Comment: You could not possibly call either items.remove(1) or items.remove("test") with this code, so you're not providing accurate information

Answer (score 1):

The "remove" methods implemented in the various interfaces that make up ArrayList take different arguments and do very different things.

If you look at the **"List interface"** there are two methods

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
    ...

    // It removes from the position in the list so it's 
    // going to work if the list has more than "index" 
    // items. So when you call it with an integer this 
    // gets used and works.

    public E remove(int index) 

    ...
    // There is a second remove method in the interface

    // This Removes an object from the list if the object 
    // equals an object in the list. So when you pass it a 
    // string ie "test" this cannot work because "test" is 
    // not a ToDoItem so the equals comparison fails.

    boolean remove(Object o);
    ...
}
```

If you want to use the **boolean remove(Object o);** method ie remove an Object you need to make sure the "equals" method is going to work in "ToDoItem". So what does your equals method look like in ToDoItem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `items` only accepts the `ToDoItem` objects.

So, `items.remove("test")` will not work. Here `"test"` is a String object.

But `items.remove(1)` will work because here you are passing an `index` value as a parameter to `remove()` method. So the object from `items` at the specified index will be removed.

To remove the specified object from `items` list, you need to pass the `ToDoItem` object as a parameter.

Read more: [How To Remove An Element From An ArrayList?](https://coderolls.com/remove-element-from-arraylist/)

Note: If you want to compare two `ToDoItem` objects by its data members values, [override the equals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/) method in `ToDoItem`.

Comment: I tried passing it as an object instead but it still didn't work. I ended up changing how my program works in the end, thanks tho!

Comment: Are you creating a new object and passing it to `remove()` method? If yes, Have you overridden the `equals()` method in your `ToDoItem` class?

If you are creating a new object (even with same param values) and passing it to arraylist remove method, it will not work. The default `equals()` method compare object reference for equality.

Comment: ArrayList remove method uses this condition to remove the object. `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`

You need to override the `equals()` method ( and then hashcode() method to [maintain the contract](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/)) to compare object.